# Converting a string to with quotes Python

Tags: python

Here is what I am trying to do:

Suppose a data set already given to me:

```
dictionary = {'products': [{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', [...]}
```

I can obtain numeric values in the dictionary as follows:
    dictionary['products'][0]['style]

I am trying to store 'products' in a variable and the 2nd keys (a, b, c, d, etc.) in another variable.

```
x = (dictionary.keys())
x = "'"+x[0]+"'"
keys = dictionary['products'][0].keys()
```

My end goal is this:

```
for i in xrange(number_of_products - 1):
    for j in xrange(len(keys) - 1):
        values[i][j] = dictionary[x][i][keys[j]] ##ERROR Here when I try to index using key[j]
```

Comment: *Why* do you need the quotes? What problem are you trying to solve? Do you need *just* the quotes, or also have non-printable characters to be escaped? Do you need to send the string somewhere else, like a template or a browser?

Comment: To emphasize what @MartijnPieters said -- if you're asking because you want to, say, substitute something into a SQL statement, or because you want to substitute something into a shell script, or to evaluate something with a Python interpreter, all three of those are different questions with completely different answers, and any of the three answers would be _completely wrong_ if given for one of the other questions.

Comment: Moreover, none of the answers below would be the right answer if you were, say, producing JSON, or inserting SQL data, or calling another process in the shell.

Comment: I need to access elements in a Dictionary, the key is 'products', so I'm trying to define a variable which can take place of the key, so something like --> print dict[x], I pulled in data from JSON and am trying to read it.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  I have changed my question to reflect what I was really trying to do

Comment: So, what's the problem with the current code, why do you think you need an additional pair of quotes?

Comment: @dawg: Just use `variable = 'products'` then `dictionary[variable]`. You **do not** need to put quotes around it.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Suppose, I didn't know my index was going to be products, I did this: x = (data.keys())
x = "'"+x[0]+"'"'...this will give x[0] = 'products'...please check the original question again.

Comment: No it will not. That will give x[0] = "'products'"

Comment: @LennartRegebro But if I keep  x = (data.keys()) and implement: print data[x][0]['url'], I get an error of "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: @dawg: Yes of course. data.keys() is a *list* of keys. Which one do you want to print?

Comment: @LennartRegebro I want to print data[x][0]['url'], but I don't want to manually input 'products'. I want to be able to read that variable from the input data and use it as "x" as an input to obtain the value stored in data[x][0]['url']

Comment: @dawg: Why don't you want to use `data['products']`? Will the key name change? Can there be more than one key?

Comment: @LennartRegebro I don't think the key will change, but I was taking precautions

Comment: @LennartRegebro If we take my "keys" as an example, there are 18 different values it can take, to write a program with 18 different cases will be annoying so I wanted to use keys as an array and use this array to index into dictionary --> please look at keys in the original problem.

Comment: @dawg The "precautions" do more harm than good. You ABSOLUTELY DO NOT need to do anything with quotes in your use case here.

Comment: @dawg: So if it can have 18 different values, iterate over the dictionary. `for key in data: data[key] ...`

Comment: If you don't want to repeatedly type `'products'`, the standard idiom is to define a faux-constant near the top of the module, such as `PRODUCTS_KEY = 'products'`. Then you use `PRODUCTS_KEY` and can be at ease knowing that you can always identify the key, that you can easily change it, and that you cannot accidentally misspell it. This practice is more popular in other languages (Java, C) than in Python, but it's not exactly unheard of. Mucking around with the quotes is **not** what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`repr()` will convert a string into its quoted representation.

```
x = 'products'
print repr(x)
```

This will correctly handle `x` containing single quotes.

Comment: Forgot about `repr` +1. The repr module has been renamed to reprlib in Python 3...

Comment: Note that `repr()` does much more than just add quotes.

Comment: @FredrikPihl `repr` is a built-in function.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: It is also a [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
>>> x = '\''+x+'\''
>>> print x
'products'
```

Similarly,

```
>>> x = "'"+x+"'"
>>> print x
'products'
```

Comment: why not simply `x = "'"+x+"'"`?

Comment: Yeah. Similar results. I'll add that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
In [4]: x = "products"

In [5]: print "'%s'" % x
'products'
```

Comment: `format()` supposed to be the right way to do it.

Comment: The `%` formatting and `format` are on equal footing — Guido pronounced that C-like formatting is not going away.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the triple quote, needn't use escape character..  anything inside a set of triple quote is considered as string

```
>>> x="""'products'"""
>>> print x
'products'
```

Comment: you can simply write `"'products'"`. for ignoring escaping, you can use raw strings: `r'\r\b'` will be treated as `'\\r\\b'`

Comment: yes, I mean using triple quote(""" or '''), we can use a  string with double quote or single quote inside it, not specifically single quote..

Answer (score 0):

A version of your code that works would look like this:

```
for i in range(len(dictionary['products'])):
    for j in dictionary['products'][i]:
        values[i][j] = dictionary['products'][i][j]
```

However, a shorter version of that is:

```
values = dictionary['products']
```

Comment: When I try to implement the first style I get an error at the second for loop: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: @dawg: Ah, right. Fixed.